# Get a list of files on google drive using PHP API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to use the API to Get a list of documents on a Google Drive then if I need to download a selected file that I query for. I cannot for the life of me figure out OAUTH and how to do this. I have a client ID , client secret key, but the documentation sucks.

I am trying to use : 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Can you you use OAUTH with out having a use give permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can you you use OAUTH with out having a use give permissions?**
No. That would defeat the purpose of OAuth.

My suggestion is start by ignoring Drive completely. Focus on understanding OAuth first.

Use the Oauth playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and this page https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 as your ONLY documentation. Everything you need to know is on those two links.

Once you have grasped Oauth, then use the Try It Now feature of https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list
to see how the Oauth token is used in your drive requests.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I figured it out. The php-google-library  has poor documentation of methods and classes. Once I got my elbows dirty it was all downhill from there.